# Represent Task[Either] and IO[Either] as a single monad that includes tryCatch?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts, tagless-final

Is there a way to represent IOEither and TaskEither as a single Monad that will also include the `tryCatch`?

I currently will consume an API over HTTP, so it makes sense to use TaskEither, but anticipate that this code will migrate "closer to home" and it would make sense to make this an `IOEither` at that point. So I want to write a consumer interface in tagless style

```js
interface EngineRepository<M extends URIS2> {
  calculateNumber: (i:SomeData) => Kind2<M, DomainError, number>
}

const getRepo = <M>(m:M extends URIS2):EngineRepository<M> => ({
  calculateNumber: someCalculation(m)()
})

const calculateNumber = <M>(m:M extends URIS2) => flow(/* M.chain, M.map, etc. works great! */)
```

So far so good! However, while there is a `tryCatch` for Option, Either, TaskEither, IOEither, etc., it's not part of any interface best I can tell. So I am trying to create my own:

```js
interface Tryable<M extends URIS2> extends Monad2<M> {
  tryCatch: <E,A>(f:Lazy<A>, onError: (reason:unknown) => E) => Kind2<M, E, A>
}

const calculateNumber = <M>(m:M extends URIS2) => 
  flow(/* M.tryCatch works great now! */)
```

The problem here is that `IOError` is sync, so `f:Lazy<A>` is fine, `TaskEither` is async, so it would need to be `f:Lazy<Promise<A>>` instead.

Is there a better way to approach this, or is this not possible? Do I need to always use TaskEither but then add a step that turns the IOEither into TaskEither and give up on tagless final?

Comment: "closer to home" meaning that currently I'm consuming an API that is a different Java microservice (so it's barely "micro" haha!), but I think another team is porting it to TypeScript and will add it to this app's code base sort of, so `IOEither`.

Comment: What is the difference between `Task` and `IO` in fp-ts - async/sync?

Comment: @scriptum yes. `interface Task<A> { ():Promise<A> }` and `interface IO<A> { ():A }`

Comment: (and by extension `TaskEither<E,A> { ():Promise<Either<E,A>> }` and `IOEither<E,A> { ():Either<E,A> }`)

Comment: I don't know fp-ts but a more general monad that can handle async (Task) and deferred/lazy sync (IO) computations with side effects is the continuation monad which is coincidentally also a monad transformer, so you can mechanically combine it with exception handling of your choice.

Comment: However, your code wouldn't be explicit about async/sync computations anymore, which is a desirable attribute in general.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tentative solution that feels hacky:

```js
interface Tryable<M extends URIS2, ThunkType extends 'Task'|'IO'> extends MonadIO2<M> {
  tryCatch: <E, A>(f:Kind<ThunkType, A>, onError: (e:unknown)=>E) => Kind2<M, E, A>
}

const te: Tryable<'TaskEither', 'Task'> = { ...TE.taskEither, tryCatch: TE.tryCatch}
const ioe: Tryable<'IOEither', 'IO'> = { ...IOE.ioEither, tryCatch: IOE.tryCatch}

pipe(te.tryCatch(()=>Promise.resolve(5),()=>'error'), te.map(num=>`${num}`)) // TaskEither<'error',string>

pipe(ioe.tryCatch(()=>5,()=>'error'), ioe.map(num => `${num}`)) // IOEither<'error',string>
```

It works, but I don't like that it couples the monads and thunk types for two reasons:

1. if we implemented `Tryable` for `Option`, the thunk type would still be `IO`. Same for `Either` and others. And *that* is where it starts feeling hacky, tightly coupling `Option` and `Either` with `IO`!
2. it's merely a fortunate coincidence thanks to duck typing that `Lazy<A>` is the same type as `IO<A>` and `Lazy<Promise<A>>` is the same type as `Task<A>`. If this were to change, this solution would not work.